# Name of theory for more users giving low ratings

Tags: terminology, case-studies

There's a theory or study that shows evidence that users are more prone to provide reviews if the review is bad than if the review is good. Kind of a "revenge" review.

However, can't find it on Google (nor here) and I need it for an article I'm writing. Maybe because I'm using the wrong search terms or because I don't remember the name of this study.

Anyways, any  help really appreciated

Note: It's not **Praise-to-Criticism Ratio** although it might be related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For how users *remember* a bad experience might be referring to [Negativity Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias). We are hard wired to give more weight to the bad (negative) than the good (positive).

**[NNGroup](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/negativity-bias-ux/)** has a piece on this:

> The negativity bias is the tendency for humans to pay more attention, or give more weight to negative experiences over neutral or positive experiences. Even when negative experiences are inconsequential, humans tend to focus on the negative.

#### How users *share* good and bad experiences:

What they do with that experience is the focus of a Zendesk study.

Here's from **[Zendesk](http://cdn.zendesk.com/resources/whitepapers/Zendesk_WP_Customer_Service_and_Business_Results.pdf)**

> 95% share bad experiences and 87% share good experiences with others.
>
> 54% shared bad experiences with more than five people and 33% shared good experiences with more than five people.

Comment: Apart from a general "people are more likely to moan if they're unhappy" bias (or part of the reason for that bias) may be that if I don't like something, there is usually _something specific_ that I don't like, therefore I might complain and mention that thing. However, if I _like_ something, there might not be any specific, stand-out feature that "makes me like it", so I might be less likely to say so.